# qt serialize qlist of pointers

Tags: qt, pointers, serialization, qlist

I'm implementing a game. 
I have a map, divided into cells that describe the terrain map. Each cell should be an instance of the class terrain. I need to serialize this map and the file has to be as small as possible since it will be synchronized over the internet between players (a few Mb if possible).
BUT 
if I create a map in this way (of size 4500x3000 cells), the file is hundred of Mb.
So I have to use pointers, as most of the terrain will be exactly the same; probably I will have around 30 different terrains.
I have this Qlist of poitners, the problem is that the file that comes out is as big as if I create all the elements and I don't understand why.
Here is my code, there are probably some big mistakes.

`map.hpp

 #ifndef MAP_HPP
 #define MAP_HPP

 #include "include.hpp"
 #include "terrain.hpp"

class map
{
public:
    map();
    map(unsigned int width, unsigned int height);
    QList<terrain*> get_grid();
    void let_snow(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
    void display_snow_map();
    void save();
    void load();

private:
    QList<terrain*> grid_;
    unsigned int width_;
    unsigned int height_;
};

----------------------------------
map.cpp

 #include "map.hpp"

map::map() {}

map::map(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) {
    width_=width;
    height_=height;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<height; i++) {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<width; j++) {
            grid_.append(new terrain(1,0,j,i));
        } 
    }
}

void map::save() {
    QFile save_file("map.brt");
    save_file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&save_file);
    out << grid_ << width_ << height_;
    save_file.close();
}

void map::load() {
    QFile load_file("map.brt");
    load_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in(&load_file);
    in >> grid_ >> width_ >> height_;
    load_file.close();
}

----------------------------
terrain.hpp

 #ifndef TERRAIN_HPP
 #define TERRAIN_HPP

 #include "include.hpp"

class terrain
{
public:
    terrain();
    terrain(qint8 type, qint8 snow, qint16 x, qint16 y);
    qint8 get_type();
    qint8 get_snow();
    qint16 get_xcoord();
    qint16 get_ycoord();
    void set_snow(qint8 snow);
    void set_xcoord(qint16 x);
    void set_ycoord(qint16 y);
    void save(QDataStream &out);
    void load();
    friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const terrain &ter);
    friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, terrain &ter);
    friend QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const terrain *ter);
    friend QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, terrain *ter);

private:
    qint8 type_;
    qint8 snow_;
    qint16 xcoord_;
    qint16 ycoord_;

};

 #endif // TERRAIN_HPP


-----------------------------------------
terrain.cpp

    QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const terrain &ter) {
    out << ter.xcoord_ << ter.ycoord_ << ter.type_ << ter.snow_;
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, terrain &ter) {
    in >> ter.xcoord_ >> ter.ycoord_ >> ter.type_ >> ter.snow_;
    return in;
}

QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &out, const terrain *ter) {
    out << ter->xcoord_ << ter->ycoord_ << ter->type_ << ter->snow_;
    return out;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &in, terrain *ter) {
    in >> ter->xcoord_ >> ter->ycoord_ >> ter->type_ >> ter->snow_;
    return in;
}`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your program do exact what **you say**, but **not what you want**. You must understand what is pointers in C++ (here you can read about it [Pointers - C++ Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)).

In your code, you really dump all your cells into file.

If you want to minimize filesize, you must think on structures of your grid. If you say that in average map you'll have nearly 30 terrains, so may be, there is no need to save your great amount of data, but use some naming system (use names for your terrains), use another data structure (for example [`QMap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html)).

Hope, you'll get my idea! Good luck!